# Synonym request for ps-vita-tv: playstation-tv

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can [playstation-tv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playstation-tv) be made a synonym of [ps-vita-tv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps-vita-tv) (or vice versa)?

The device originally launched as Vita TV in Asia but has been released as PlayStation TV in other regions e.g. North America.